# Detecting rising edge synchronization of 2 different clocks

Tags: vhdl, edge-detection, xilinx-ise

How do you detect rising edge synchronization of 2 different clocks(different frequencies) in VHDL programming using Xilinx software?

There is a main clock of frequency 31.845 Mhz , and another clock of frequency 29.972 Mhz. So the basic aim is to trigger an action when there is synchronization between the rising edges of 2 clocks. We tried implementing it using flipflops but we could achieve only Level synchronization, not Edge sync.

And we cannot compare the rising edges of 2 different clocks in statements like `IF` and `WAIT` in vhdl, So that is out of question.

We are trying to count pulses using a counter. For that, we need to stop the count whenever edge matching takes place. We are trying to implement a method called 'Vernier Interpolation'.

1. Initially, we used the following statement code, but since rising edges of 2 different clocks (clk0, clk1) cannot be compared in an `IF` statement, we had to drop it.

   `if(rising_edge(clk0)=rising_edge(clk1)) then wait;`
2. We then tried using `WAIT` statements (`wait until`) but it failed.
3. Then we tried using flipflops and delay circuits (D flipflop), but it resulted in level sync, and not Edge sync.

Comment: What is your overall objective and what are the frequency ranges for the clocks.

Comment: There is a main clock of frequency 31.845 Mhz , and another clock of frequency 29.972 Mhz. So the basic aim is to trigger an action when there is synchronization between the rising edges of 2 clocks. We tried implementing it using flipflops but we could achieve only Level synchronization, not Edge sync.

Comment: And we cannot compare the rising edges of 2 different clocks in statements like IF and WAIT in vhdl, So that is out of question.

Comment: When you say you are looking for synchronisation, there must be some tolerance here. What do you plan to do with the resulting signal? Is it some sort of PLL? This is all information that should really go in the question itself.

Comment: We are trying to count pulses using a counter. For that, we need to stop the count whenever edge matching takes place. We are trying to implement a method called 'Vernier Interpolation'.

Comment: 1)Initially, we used the following statement code, but since rising edges of 2 different clocks (clk0,clk1) cannot be compared in an IF statement, we had to drop it.                                                                  if(rising_edge(clk0)=rising_edge(clk1)) then
    wait;
2)We then tried using WAIT statements (wait until) but it failed.                3)Then we tried using flipflops and delay circuits (D flipflop), but it resulted in level sync, and not Edge sync.

Comment: I can't think of an obvious answer straight away, but if you edit your question to include the information from your comments, it might make it easier for other people to understand the problem and perhaps come up with a solution.

Comment: Okay sure. Let me know in case you come up with anything.

Comment: Even if you could describe your intended design in VHDL, it wont synthesis for an FPGA, because you are seeking for a custom made digital or more likely analog circuit. It's called phase comparator.

Comment: If you are trying to detect when the rising edges on the two clocks are aligned, the only pure-digital mechanism I can think of is to oversample both the clocks at a much higher rate, do an edge detect on each, and determine (within some jitter relative to the oversampling clock) when they both having rising edges.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  What you will get out is a new clock at the beat frequency between the two clocks.

The correct way to do this is to sample both clocks using another clock which is at least twice the frequency of the highest expected input.  You could generate this higher clock using one of the PLLs in the device.  x2 is a minimum. Ideally use a clock which is much higher than both sampled clocks.

Remember VHDL is not a language, it a description of synthesis of real hardware.  So just saying Rising_Edge(clk1) = Rising_Edge(clk2) does not make the 'software' detect edges.  All the function Rising_Edge really does is to tell the hardware to connect the clk signal to the clock input of a flipflop.

The proper solution is sample both 'clocks' in a process which is clocked by the a sample clock, look for edges (an edge being two subsequent samples that are different) then AND the result and latch if required.

sample code (untested, sorry no time right now).

```
entity twoclocks is
 port (
    op : out std_logic;
    clk1 : in std_logic;
    clk2 : in std_logic;
    sample_clk : in std_logic);
end entity;


architecture RTL of twoclocks is

begin

process sample(sample_clock, clk1, clk2):
begin
    if rising_edge(sample_clock):
      clk1_d <= clk1;
      clk2_d <= clk1;
      if clk1_d != clk1 and clk2_d != clk2 then
        op <= '1';
      else
        op <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: ... there's probably an offset in phase, which needs to be determined ;) Else you would be right. :P Lookup vernier interpolator.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of vernier interpolator you want needs to be build using very tight timing constraints, thus you can probably not make it using VHDL alone. You need (a lot of) device specific constraints on resource locations and timing.

Please check out [the work by A.Aloisio et al.](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1158663/files/p383.pdf). Aloisio and colleagues have build a vernier interpolator using specific Xilinx delay elements.

Standard VHDL synthesis is mostly suited for register transfer level descriptions. I.e. clocked/synchronous logic. But to compare these two inputs, you would need to sample them at a frequency of the least common multiple of both frequencies. For 31.845 MHz and 29.972 MHz that is a whopping 954.458340 MHz, which is a lot. I have seen these kind of speeds in FPGA logic though.
... But I'm thinking you might even need to double that, due to Nyquist. Maybe FPGA logic can nowadays handle 2 GHz swichting rate. But I'm not sure.

It might be possible to utilize a GT transceiver for this, but since that would be non-standard use of a such a transceiver, it might be hard to realize.